# What should a PetscBag be used for?

Tags: petsc

I've been trying to use a PetscBag to read in a number of options I want to pass to a program I'm writing. Before I came across the documentation for PetscBag, I was planning on using a struct and a function that would take the struct and use `PetscOptionsGetSometype()` to set all the values in the struct.

I figured that PetscBag would save some code, but seeing as each variable in the PetscBag has to use `PetscOptionsRegisterSometype()`, it looks to be just as much code to use the PetscBag as not to use it.

On the other hand, I don't know that much about how the struct I was going to use would work when run with MPI.

What should a PetscBag be used for? What advantages do they have over vanilla structs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Items in a PetscBag are self-documenting though the associated help strings (seen when you run with `-help` and with `PetscBagView()`, can be overridden at run-time through the options database (`-prefix_fieldname 4.2e7`), and are serializable in ASCII and portable binary. With a normal struct, you have to write code to take input, supply help, and serialize (including dealing with backward compatibility as you add new fields).

It's a reasonable thing to use for a collection of problem-specific data, e.g. specification of a physical model configuration. It's not a good place to put "problem-sized data" such as an unstructured mesh or high-dimensional observational data.